# How to register custom IExceptionFilter implementation with AutoFac

Tags: asp.net, inversion-of-control, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5

ASP.NET MVC 5
Custom Global Error Handler

How to register a custom global exception attribute with AutoFac IoC Container?

```
public class ExceptionLoggingFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    private IRepo _repo;
    public ExceptionLoggingFilter(IRepo repo)
    {
        this._repo = repo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the pattern outlined for other action filter types [as noted in the documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#enable-property-injection-for-action-filters). There are extension methods for all the filter types.

```
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
builder.RegisterType<ExceptionLoggingFilter>()
       .AsExceptionFilterFor<MyController>();
```

Alternatively, use attributes with property injection and just register the filter provider.